# I calculated $\lim_{x\to 0} {\sin x\over x}$ as 0.01745 instead of 1

Tags: calculus, limits, numerical-methods

When using a graphing utility to generate a table, I got 0.01745 as the limit rather than 1. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Can you post the table? How small of values did you use for $x$?

Comment: Were you possible in the wrong mode? Degrees vs. radians.

Comment: When you used degrees instead of radians. Reset your calculator to radians, and it all works out.

Comment: You made the _usual_ mistake.

Answer (score 18):

Your calculator was in the wrong mode.  You need to be in radians for most formulae to hold regarding trig functions.  Once you switch it into radians, your table should be fine - showing that the limit is indeed $1.$

Fun fact: If you were in degrees, the limit should come out to $\frac{\pi}{180} \approx .01745$ which is what you had.

Comment: Ah, nice catch!